# Getting "upstream connect errors" when browsing my Grafana deployment on K8s/Istio

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, istio, istio-sidecar, istio-gateway

I'm using Grafana v7.3.3 connected to a PostgreSQL. I have it running in a Kubernetes environment using Istio, deployed via ArgoCD. Everything will work fine with the site about 50% of the time, but the other 50% of the timeit will have the following types of errors:

1. 503 Service Unavailable -> upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination
2. Error upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination

I then refresh the page and then half the time it will work properly again. I'm not really seeing anything in the app logs nor Istio logs that can give me any clues. Anyone know what I can start looking at to fix this?

And the errors are sporadic, so it works for a few minutes then you click around or refresh the page, and it is broken, then you refresh and it works fine.

Comment: Check if your Grafana pod is crashing often? Do you monitor for OOM events on your cluster?

Comment: Looks like an intermittent connectivity issue, but I don't know enough about the setup (logs, configs) to debug this. Try looking at the follow to see if the solutions apply to you. 
* Expose grafana publicly using istio
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63689505
* Istio mtls connection issues
https://discuss.istio.io/t/istio-mtls-connection-issues/4215

Please post log snippets if you see any errors.

Comment: You've already added a bounty. Please don't post junk answers to bump your post.